# Nullpointer error in exercise

Tags: c++, nullpointerexception, operator-overloading

My experience so far is mostly in Java but i'm trying to learn C++ and i'm still struggling to understand pointers, overloads etc. Forgive me about the title but i didn't know how to present my problem. Anyway i came across this exercise while studying and i would like some help. The exercise provides a class Container and a main() and i'm supposed to extend the Class and make the main() work to provide the proper result.

```
template <typename T>
class Container
{
 protected:
     T * storage;
     size_t num_items;
     size_t storage_size;

public:
    virtual void operator += (const T item) { }
    virtual ~Container() { }
    Container() : storage(nullptr), num_items(0), storage_size(0) { }
    T operator [] (size_t index)
    {
        if (num_items==0)
        return T(0);
        return storage[index<num_items?index:num_items];
    }
    inline size_t size() { return num_items; }
    };



void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Container<long> * store = new Container_ex(); // I'm suppose to fill this gap
                                 ---------------
    size_t num_data;
    cin >> num_data;
    for (size_t i=0; i<num_data; i++)
    {
        long item;
        cin >> item;
        *store+=item;
    }
    for (size_t i=0; i<store->size(); i++)
        std::cout << (*store)[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    delete store;
}
```

So far i've done this. The problem lies when i try to overload += cause i get an exception error `(this->storage was nullptr)` but in any case i don't understand the use of storage completely in this exercise so i would appreciate any help.

```
class Container_ex : public Container<long> {
public:
    Container_ex() : Container() {}
    ~Container_ex() { delete[] storage; }
    void operator += (const long item) 
    {
        *storage = const_cast<long&>(item);  
        *storage = *storage + item; 
        num_items = num_items + 1;
        storage_size = storage_size + 1; 
    }

};
```

Comment: Where did you ever allocate memory for `storage`?

Comment: Should i do it inside the operator overload ? Cause the given constructor in Container initialized it with null

Comment: `storage` is a pointer, but it doesn't actually *point* anywhere. You need to make it point somewhere before you can dereference it.

Comment: Also, judging by the name `Container`, the use of the `operator[]` overload and the `num_items` and `storage_size` members, I think you're supposed to create a dynamic array, and the `+=` operator should append to the end of the dynamic array.

Comment: Oh, i see i'll try that!

Comment: `void main(int argc, char* argv[])` that's undefined behavior. You should use an entry point that is defined in the standard. All of them return an `int`. Take a step back and think whether you want to follow a tutorial that cannot even get the first basic line correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pointer needs to point on a valid memory address before you can do anything with it. If it doesn't, it leads to undefined behavior that can end in a crash of your application, for example.

But when do you need to do it ? **Certainly not in the operator overload**. When you create an object, you must ensure that it is in a valid state. It means either setting it to `nullptr` so it is a null pointer, or allocating memory for it.

If you do it in operator overload, how can you be sure that operator overloading will be used ? Maybe the user just wants doing `[]`. So you have to make a constructor allocating memory for your pointer. Or, better, use [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) that will save your life and provent headaches, especially if you come from a language where there is no explicit pointer like Java.

Finally, there are some great books to learn C++ better than the course you use.

- **[Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321992784)** by **Bjarne Stroustrup**, the creator of C++. Assume no previous experience in programming. Check to take the updated version for C++11 | C++14.
- **[C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321714113)** by **Stanley Lippman**, **Josée Lajoie** and **Barbara E. Moo**. ~1k pages, full of details and explanations on C++11. Good for beginners with a previous experience in programming.